# Using a Dictionary as input parameter on Attribute Routing

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, rest

I have the following RESTful Action on an MVC-project:

```
[Route("save")]
[HttpPut]
public ActionResult UpdateAllSettings(Dictionary<string,object> values){}
```

Currently I am stuck sending values to that Action. I tried using the following JSON-Structure:

```
fancyData="'values':[{'key':'k1','value':'v1'}]";
$http({url:'myurl',data: fancyData}
```

but values is always null.

I also tried replacing `Dictionary<string,object>` by `List<KeyValuePair<string,object>>` with the same results

Comment: fancyData does not contains a valid JSON

Comment: @T-moty Just wanted to write a simple version of more complex realworld-Data. Should be fine now

Comment: yep. As far as i know, the default model binder search for a case-sensitive property name match: try change your json property names to camel case. Also try debug that service with a breakpoint, and see what happen when you send values (this.Request on controller).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell the action to look for data in the request body:

```
public ActionResult UpdateAllSettings([FromBody]Dictionary<string,object> values){}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case it would be better that you decorate the `values` parameter with the `FromBody` attribute. This gives you the benefit that when creating the `PUT` request you can add the `JSON`-content as content to the request.

```
httpClient.PutAsync("URL", new StringContent("YOUR JSON HERE",
                                             Encoding.UTF8,
                                             "application/json"));
```

To have better reusability just derive from StringContent and create a JSONContent-class:

```
public sealed class JsonContent : StringContent
{
    public JsonContent(object content)
        : base(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content))
    {
    }

    public JsonContent(object content, Encoding encoding)
        : base(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content), encoding, "application/json")
    {
    }
}
```

> Note I use Json.NET as JSON library

now you can modify it to:

```
httpClient.PutAsync("URL", new JsonContent(yourDictionaryHere,
                                           Encoding.UTF8,
                                           "application/json"));
```